# Populating two one-dimensional arrays with text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, streamreader

For my Visual Basic final, my program is required to read data from a text file into two different arrays, each being one-dimensional. The following is my code for doing so:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Option Strict On

Public Class frmMain

    'Constant for filename and a dirty flag variable
    Const INVENTORY_FILENAME As String = "inventory.txt"
    Dim noFile As Boolean = False

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Populates DVD listbox with text file data upon load

        'Variable for reading the file
        Dim myFile As IO.StreamReader

        'Declaring arrays for DVD names and prices
        Dim arrayDVD() As String
        Dim arrayPrice() As Double

        'Variables for populating arrays with respective data
        Dim dvdName As String
        Dim dvdPrice As Double
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        'Checking that file exists then reading data to each array
        If IO.File.Exists(INVENTORY_FILENAME) Then
            myFile = IO.File.OpenText(INVENTORY_FILENAME)

            'Read data to arrays
            Do Until myFile.Peek = -1
                dvdName = myFile.ReadLine()
                dvdPrice = Double.Parse(myFile.ReadLine())

                arrayDVD = dvdName
                arrayPrice = dvdPrice

                'Using arrays to populate multicolumn listbox
                lstDVD.Items.Add(arrayDVD(i) & arrayPrice(i))

                i += 1

            Loop

            'Closing the file
            myFile.Close()

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

The text file alternates names and prices of DVDs to be read as individual lines, making the arrays parallel:

```
Pulp Fiction
9.99
Jumanji
13.99
And so on...
```

I'm receiving a value type error code stating that I cannot convert 'String' to 'String()' or convert 'Double' to 'Double()' when setting the arrays' values equal to their respective variables. Is there a way to correct this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this VBA or from a Visual Basic compiler version?

Comment: This is not VBA

Comment: It's poor practice to check File.Exists(). It adds an additional file I/O action, which is absolutely the the slowest thing you can do inside a single computer: even worse than unwinding the stack to handle an exception. And speaking of exceptions, the file system is *volatile*, meaning you still need code to handle them when (not if) something goes wrong. So since the I/O from the exists check is slower than the exception, and you have to write the exception code anyway, you may just as well _not check Exists() at all_, and rely solely on the exception handler.

Comment: Also, paired arrays that match up by index are poor practice, (you should one array of a class with two properties instead), but it seems like that's a requirement of the problem so we'll leave that discussion for another day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
arrayDVD = dvdName
arrayPrice = dvdPrice
```

`arrayDVD` and `arrayPrice` are **arrays**. You need to assign to a *specific element* in each of those arrays:

```
arrayDVD(i) = dvdName
arrayPrice(i) = dvdPrice
```

Don't forget to make sure the arrays actually have enough elements for this.

*Hint: `ReDim Preserve` is pretty much the least efficient way possible to make sure an array is big enough. Each use will allocate a brand new array, copy the elements one at a time, assign the new array to the old reference, and then release the old array. It does **not** preserve in-place. Nevertheless, if this is a 100-level course it might be what you are expected to do at this point.*

Finally, you should **never** use `Double` when working with money (use `Decimal` instead).

---

Separate from the question, here is how I might approach this without the weird array limitation:

```
Private Iterator Function ReadInventoryFile(filePath As String) As IEnumerable(Of (String, Decimal))
    Using rdr As New StreamReader(filePath)
          Dim DVDName As String = Nothing
          While (DVDName = rdr.ReadLine()) IsNot Nothing
                Yield (DVDName, Decimal.Parse(rdr.ReadLine()))
          End While
    End Using
End Function

Const INVENTORY_FILENAME As String = "inventory.txt"
Private data As List(Of (String, Decimal))

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try 'Replaces the File.Exists() check
        data = ReadInventoryFile(INVENTORY_FILENAME).ToList()

        For Each item As (String, Decimal) In data
            lstDVD.Items.Add($"{item.Item1}{vbTab}{item.Item2:C}")
        Next
    Catch
        ' Actually do something here. Empty catch blocks are rarely correct.
        ' Note I catch at this level, rather than in the ReadFile() method.
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did end up having to use ReDim (it is a basics class so this method has actually been discussed). After doing that and applying the indexes to the loop it works perfectly!